# Bookdown: Exporting to a word document (Error in files2[[format]] : attempt to select less than one element in get1index)

Tags: r, r-markdown, bookdown

I am writing my thesis using the bookdown package and the memoir latex class. Everything works relatively fine when I am exporting to pdf or to html but I am unable to export the thesis to a word document...

I get the following mysterious error:

```
Error in files2[[format]] : 
  attempt to select less than one element in get1index
```

It is difficult to provide a reproducible example though, as I am working from my messy dissertation repository.

But here is (a part of) my _output.yml file:

```
bookdown::pdf_book:
  includes:
    in_header: latex/preamble.tex # defines style and latex options
    before_body: latex/before_body.tex # defines cover page
  latex_engine: xelatex # lualatex or xelatex
  citation_package: none # needs to be "none" in order to use the csl file
  keep_tex: true # keeps the .tex file
  dev: "cairo_pdf"
  toc: false # deactivates default table of contents
  highlight: pygments # code highlighting
  pandoc_args: [ "--csl", "./csl/apa6.csl" ] # specifies the csl file to be used

bookdown::word_document2:
  pandoc_args: [
    "--csl", "./csl/apa6.csl",
    "--bibliography", "./bib/packages.bib",
    "--bibliography", "./bib/thesis.bib",
    #"--reference-doc", "./assets/2018-05-17-aim1-draft.docx",
    "--filter", "pandoc-citeproc"
    #"--filter", "./assets/fix-apa-ampersands.py"
  ]
```

Any idea ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a bug of the **bookdown** package, which [I just fixed](https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown/commit/25ea15435a3a0898556d22b7fa2e232f5f5e3cb1) on Github. Please try the development version there:

```r
remotes::install_github('rstudio/bookdown')
```

Comment: Thanks for your prompt answer ! It works now, but (for information) I get the same error when using the `bookdown::preview_chapter()` function...

Comment: Exactly the same error (i.e. `Error in files2[[format]]`)? I cannot think of a reason why that could possibly happen. Did you restart your R session?

Comment: You're right, it works fine after restarting the session, thanks !