# Specify files with bookdown's `rmd_files` for word document output? I get "Error in basename(files)"

Tags: docx, bookdown

Following @yihui's [bookdown usage 1.3](https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/usage.html), I'm attempting to select specific files to render in each output format by adding a `rmd_files` argument to _bookdown.yml in @yihui's Minimal Book Example.

```
rmd_files:
  html: ["index.Rmd", "01-intro.Rmd"]
  latex: ["index.Rmd", "01-intro.Rmd"]
  epub: ["index.Rmd", "01-intro.Rmd"]
  word: ["index.Rmd", "01-intro.Rmd"]
```

To  _output.yml, I add

```
bookdown::word_document2:
  toc: true
```

Everything else in the Minimal Book Example is unchanged.

`rmarkdown::render_site(encoding = 'UTF-8')` renders html, latex, and epub documents, but word output fails with `Error in basename(files) : a character vector argument expected Calls: <Anonymous> ... FUN -> render_book -> source_files -> grep -> basename`

The word document renders if I remove the `rmd_files` argument.

I tried omitting index.Rmd from the files list, deleting all content from both Rmd files, and using `word_document` instead of `word_document2`.

Same results with CRAN bookdown_0.20 and development version 0.20.3 on two different machines (both macs).

This error may be similar to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56061122/bookdown-exporting-to-a-word-document-error-in-files2format-attempt-to-s), but it did not provide a minimal example and appears to have been fixed in the latest bookdown release.

Bookdown is amazing, and I could be missing something simple here. Thanks so much for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name of the output format is `docx` instead of `word`.

```yaml
rmd_files:
  docx: ["index.Rmd", "01-intro.Rmd"]
```

The name is for Pandoc, and all names are listed here: https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#option--to

Comment: Thank you! This could be useful to note in 1.3 since the other options have the same names as output options given--"LaTeX, HTML, EPUB, and Word". It's obvious in hindsight, but it looks others have been confused by this little mismatch (e.g. https://www.barelysignificant.com/post/old/blogdown/). Thanks again!

Comment: @DevinJudge-Lord Since this is too confusing, I just made `word` work automatically: https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown/commit/4bff22cd447015ce5ebe953e562dc2d2b5490685 Thanks!